# Check if a string has 2 characters next to each other - Python

Tags: python, string, char

Say we have a string

```
"SS in a dark room"
True
```

I want to check if this string contains 2 or more 'S' characters next to each other, so here it would be True but in this string it would be False:

```
"ss in a dark room"
False
```

Here it would be False:

```
"S in a dark room" 
False
```

and here it would be True

```
"SSS in me"
True
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
the_string = "SS in a dark room"
print("SS" in the_string)
## Returns True
```

Comment: Use python3's syntax print()